# Does autocomplete help keep spam at bay?

Tags: autocomplete, spam-prevention, bots

I'm wondering if using autocomplete fields, like SO uses for tags in question posts, goes some way to filtering out spammers/bots.

If the field requires a user to make a selection according to some simple rules, this may mean that the bot can't proceed effectively.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete has no effect whatsoever on spam bots. It does not affect anything they do - it's only offering suggestions as you type. You can type whatever you want, totally ignoring the suggested text. Spambots likely won't have the Javascript enabled that permits autocomplete to work, anyway.